# How can I get a dictionary of group name -> contents from a Julia RegexMatch?

Tags: regex, julia

I wrote a regex containing named groups. I can see the regexmatch object contains the keys and values, but I'm not sure how I would extract a dictionary from it...

For example, if I have

> r"(?<my_num>\d*) (?<the_rest>.*)"

how would I get a dictonary containing the keys "my_num" and "the_rest", without having to keep track of those keys elsewhere?

Comment: The RegEx is `r"(?P<my_num>\d*) (?P<the_rest>.*)"` with the group names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to access the groups use:

```
julia> m  = match(r"^([a-z]*)([1-9]*)([a-z]*)$","abc123abc")
RegexMatch("abc123abc", 1="abc", 2="123", 3="abc")

julia> m[1]
"abc"

julia> m[2]
"123"
```

or to create a dictionary with the group numbers as keys:

```
julia> d = Dict(i=>m[i] for i=1:3)
Dict{Int64,SubString{String}} with 3 entries:
  2 => "123"
  3 => "abc"
  1 => "abc"
```

or if you meant to work with *named groups* as keys:

```
julia> re = r"(?P<group1>a*)(?P<group2>b*)$"
r"(?P<group1>a*)(?P<group2>b*)$"

julia> m  = match(re,"aaabbb")
RegexMatch("aaabbb", group1="aaa", group2="bbb")

julia> d = Dict(Symbol(n)=>m[Symbol(n)] for n in values(Base.PCRE.capture_names(m.regex.regex)))
Dict{Symbol,SubString{String}} with 2 entries:
  :group1 => "aaa"
  :group2 => "bbb"

julia> d[:group1]
"aaa"

julia> m[2]
"bbb"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However, I'm curious about regexes with named groups in particular -- i.e. r"(?<my_name>.*)" -- and how to extract these keys from the regex itself instead of having to keep track of them separately. Actually, I'll update the question...

Comment: Ding! Thank you!

Comment: Actually... if I could ask one more question... how would I have found that out on my own?

Comment: First, I saw the RegexMatch showed the group names and so I folloed the source of `show(STDOUT,m)`

Comment: Huh! That's super useful. Thanks, Dan :)

Comment: ...and assuming I wrote "so I followed" with a w ;)